# Is there an AJAX framework that does this?

Tags: javascript, ajax, orm, frameworks

I'm about to embark upon developing a "fully AJAX" web application where I do not generate any HTML pages on the server but only respond to AJAX calls, that too only in JSON. The app is pretty much a CRUD interface for a database. I want a framework where if I define my model (database table structures and relations) my server-side code as well as JSON objects could be auto-generated, so that all I've to do in Javascript is to instantiate an object, populate it and call a .save() on it and it'll get saved to the database (the AJAX call hence becomes transparent). I can then concentrate on programming the app UI. I understand it may not be as simple as a .save() but perhaps the .save() functionality would be split across multiple Javascript methods since the AJAX call would be asynchronous.

Is there a framework that provides this ORM like functionality in Javascript and makes the AJAX calls transparent? I can of course do a search for 'AJAX Frameworks' and then study each framework, but that'd be a rather lengthy process .. I know there are some 'AJAX Frameworks' out there that are nothing like this but just provide some helper functions for facilitating AJAX calls.

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you search for "ajax crud framework" instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your case looks like it needs [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as client-side frameworks go, [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) is along these lines. It’s a JavaScript MVC framework, so you create models to represent your data and views to render the data.

Their model class does indeed have [a `save()` method](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-save) for sending the data back to the server in JSON form.

It’s purely client-side though, so you will have to set up the server yourself, and then reproduce the server models in corresponding Backbone models on the client. You might be able to write some code on the server to auto-generate the Backbone model classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a look at [todomvc](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/) where various javascript frameworks are compared. Backbone is included there, as well as ember.js (the old sproutcore, the new version).

You are actually looking for a Model Binding Framework, where data models from javascript are persisted in the backend (or other persistence layers like WebSQL) as well as in the UI (the HTML) which is dynamically generated via templates and JSON data stored in models.